# Cannot setup hostname and FQDN Centos 7

Tags: centos, hostname

I'm now running CentOS-7.0-1406 and looks like i can't setup hostname properly. As far as i know, you need to setup hostname using **hostnamectl set-hostname** command and write FQDN in /etc/hosts.
I have a centos machine and i want to set it's hostname to "server" and FQDN to "server.mydomain.com". I run hostnamectl command and edit /etc/hosts file:

```
[root@server ~]# hostnamectl set-hostname server
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

{inet_IP_here} server.mydomain.com server
```

At first everything looks fine, console displays hostname when i run **hostname** and it displays FQDN when i run **hostname -f**:

```
[root@server ~]# hostname
server
[root@server ~]# hostname -f
server.mydomain.com
```

BUT after i reboot machine and run the same commands again, it starts to display FQDN as hostname:

```
[root@server ~]# hostname
server.mydomain.com
```

I must say that it's a VPS server and *i have no such problem* when i do it on a local virtual machine. Also there is no any settings in VPS control panel which look like hostname. What reason might cause such problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Red Hat documentation explicitly instructs you to [use the fully qualified domain name as the machine's static hostname](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Configure_Host_Names.html). Trying to name a server with a single unqualified name causes a variety of problems with various services, most notably email.

> A host name can be a free-form string up to 64 characters in length. However, Red Hat recommends that both static and transient names match the *fully-qualified domain name* (FQDN) used for the machine in DNS, such as `host.example.com`.

You should be doing:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname server.example.com
```

You can also manually edit `/etc/hostname` for the same effect; again, it should contain the FQDN.

```
# cat /etc/hostname
server.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly set up hostname and FQDN on CentOS 7, you need to set up /etc/hostname to contain short, node name, like:

```
# echo server > /etc/hostname
```

And you need to add domain entry in resolv.conf:

```
# echo 'domain mydomain.com' >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot afterwards.

Note: entry from resolv.conf can be lost after reboot, so to keep it, it may be neccesarry to set up DOMAIN= in your network-scripts, like:

```
echo 'DOMAIN="mydomain.com"' >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Replace eth0 with your appropriate interface, like for example enp3s0.

Answer (score -2):

```
cat /etc/hostname
server01

cat /etc/hosts

192.168.100.10 server01.test.com server01
```

Now you can check it.

`hostname` (would output) `server01`

`hostname -f` (would output) `server01.test.com`

Answer (score -5):

Echo "kernel.hostname = my.com" >> /etc/sysctl.conf