# echo $HOSTNAME result become key to a variable

Tags: linux

Can someone please help me with a bash script? Can't seem to wrap my mind aoround it.

Property

```
server1=abc,def,ghc
server2=xyz,tes,iuy


echo $server1
abc,def,ghc

echo $HOSTNAME
server1
```

with those info above, I want to output the output "abc,def,ghc" in a test variable.

```
echo \$$HOSTNAME
$server1

bash-4.1$ test=`echo \$$HOSTNAME`
bash-4.1$ echo $test
8722HOSTNAME
```

If someone can pls help me get this done in perl/bash or any code I can use pls. Thank you.

Comment: I aborted my attempt to edit and clean up your question. Not completely clear what's what to be quite honest. Try using backticks for inline code (``) and code blocks (`{}` button in the formatting bar).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for:

```
${!HOSTNAME}
```

e.g.

```
echo ${!HOSTNAME}
```

This is generally known as a nested variable. The bash man page explains how this construct works:

```
       ${!prefix*}
              Names matching prefix. Expands to the names of variables whose
              names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the
              IFS special variable.
```

But, beware in this particular circumstance, because `$HOSTNAME` generally contains the hostname of the computer, which is [supposed to be a fully qualified domain name](https://serverfault.com/a/666872/126632), and these contain dots, which are not valid in bash variable names.

Comment: +1 for even understanding what they were asking. Impressive.